# Unable to determine the principal end of the relationship on saving Order - EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am adding EF6 and trying to recreate the model of my legacy db. I am also making a WCF web service. There are way too many fields, so I've minimized the example to better pinpoint the problem.

I am trying to enter some data into the database for an Order. The Order includes OrderLines and each OrderLine can have licenses. OrderLine is one to many on rare occasions so I have to do one to many. If one OrderLine and License is for a part, the next OrderLine and License is for Maintenance for that part. The part license must link to the maintenance license.

[image]

ParentLicenceId is the issue. In my legacy db, there is the relationship between one License and another License that is of PartType Maintenance. So if a customer buys Part X, they might by 1 year of maintenance for Part X. So the Part X Maintenance License will list the Part X license as it's parent.

```
using OrderExample;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace OrderExampleCmd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var omc = new OrderExampleEntities();
            var order = new Order
            {
                OrderNumber = new Guid().ToString(),
                OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>()
            };
            // Maitenance
            var orderLine1 = new OrderLine
            {
                OrderLineNumber = 1,
                Licenses = new List<License>()
            };
            var orderLine1License = new License
            {
                LicenseType = "Maintenance"
            };
            orderLine1.Licenses.Add(orderLine1License);

            // Part
            var orderLine2 = new OrderLine
            {
                OrderLineNumber = 2,
                Licenses = new List<License>()
            };
            var orderLine2License = new License
            {
                LicenseType = "Part",
                MaintenanceLicense = orderLine1License
            };
            orderLine1License.PartLicenses.Add(orderLine2License);

            order.OrderLines.Add(orderLine1);
            order.OrderLines.Add(orderLine2);

            omc.Orders.Add(order);
            omc.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

There error message occurs at omc.SaveChanges() and is this:

Unable to determine the principal end of the 'OrderExampleModel.LicenseParentLicense' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

I have tried:

1. [Multiple added entities may have the same primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041057/multiple-added-entities-may-have-the-same-primary-key) but I am already using the object property and not the id property.

I've gone through several other articles. I'm hoping there is just some advanced setting I need to apply.

How do I get past this error to save these changes?

Comment: Is `MaintenanceLicense` optional / required ?

Comment: Maintenance License is optional. One could buy a part without Maintenance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is caused by temporary non unique primary keys detected in the attached entities. You need to assign temporary primary keys and foreign keys for order lines.

> When a new entity is created, the Entity Framework defines temporary
>   key and sets the IsTemporary property to true. When you call the
>   SaveChanges method, the Entity Framework assigns a permanent key and
>   sets the IsTemporary property to false. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd283139%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

By default `orderLine1` and `orderLine2` have the same temporary primary keys that are 0 (default value of integer), you need to set them temporary to prevent 2 order lines have the same temporary id (that is 0).

```
orderLine1.OrderLineId = 1;
orderLine1License.OrderLineId = 1;

orderLine2.OrderLineId = 2;
orderLine2License.OrderLineId = 2;
```

Comment: I'll check on this. Thanks Yuliam.

Comment: That worked. I would have never thought to set the id fields, assuming that setting them would actually make them try to be used. I didn't know about the IsTemporary setting.

Comment: @Rhyous, it's used to make a relationship prior submitting, like _header - detail relationship_, `IsTemporary` is located somewhere in the `EdmKey`, what we need to do is just assigning the temporary primary key and foreign key manually

Comment: I also presumed that I ought not set the Id property of a new object if that Id is configured to be DatabaseGenerated - now I know better!